# Set timezone using node wekit and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I'm developing an application using angularJS and node webkit.

I'm trying to display a date using this code :

```
<td>{{message._dateTimestamp | date : 'shortDate'}}</td>
```

But it displays me in the US format and not the european one. Angular's documentation explains the timezone depends on the user's browser. But I'm using nodewebkit so I guess the default timezone is US.

Is there a way to detect automatically the timezone depending from the Os ?
If not what is the best way to let the user choose its timezone ?

Thank you

Comment: current timezone offset. `new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -1`

Comment: This can give me the local time but will not help the formatting of the dates ?